# gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons creating dialog box and assigning different values in the attribute filed

Tags: c++, dialog, widget, gtk, messagebox

I want to print "VaribleString" this variable in the dialog . I have tried with different ways like:-

```
    std::string VaribleString;

DialogWidget  = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons (VaribleString,
                                  GTK_WINDOW(webkitBrowserWindow) ,
                                  flags,
                                  "YES",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_YES,
                                  "NO",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_NO,
                                  NULL);
```

And

```
DialogWidget  = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("%s",VaribleString.c_str(),
                                  GTK_WINDOW(webkitBrowserWindow) ,
                                  flags,
                                  "YES",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_YES,
                                  "NO",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_NO,
                                  NULL);
```

And

```
DialogWidget  = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons (VaribleString.c_str(),
                                  GTK_WINDOW(webkitBrowserWindow) ,
                                  flags,
                                  "YES",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_YES,
                                  "NO",
                                  GTK_RESPONSE_NO,
                                  NULL);
```

But it is not working. Can any one help on it?

Comment: Did you assign the value to your string variable prior to using it? Passing in `VaribleString.c_str()` should suffice.

Comment: Yes at first  ,i  assigned the value in the variable and after that i tried to used it but string is not coming in the dialog box.